# "invalid label" Firebug error with jQuery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsonp, firebug

I'm making a jQuery `$.getJSON` request to another domain, so am making sure that my GET URI ends with "callback=?" (i.e. using JSONP).

The NET panel of Firebug shows that I am receiving the data as expected, but for some reason the Console panel logs the following error: "invalid label".

The JSON validates with [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com), so I doubt that there is anything truly wrong with the structure of the data.

Any ideas why I might be receiving this error?

Comment: Please show us the Javascript rendered by the JSONP request.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old post, but I'm posting a response anyway:

Let's assume you want to get the jSON code generated by the following file, "get_json_code.php":

```
<?php
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Like you mentioned, $.getJSON() uses JSONP when you add a "jsoncallback=?" parameter to the required URL's string. For example:

```
$.getJSON("http://mysite.com/get_json_code.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data){ 
   alert(data);
});
```

However, in this case, you will get an "invalid label" message in Firebug because the "get_json_code.php" file doesn't provide a valid reference variable to hold the returned jSON string. To solve this, you need add the following code to the "get_json_code.php" file:

```
<?php
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($arr).')'; //assign resulting code to $_GET['jsoncallback].
?>
```

This way, the resulting JSON code will be added to the 'jsoncallback' GET variable.

In conclusion, the "jsoncallback=?" parameter in the $.getJSON() URL does two things: 1) it sets the function to use JSONP instead of JSON and 2) specifies the variable that will hold the JSON code retrieved from the "get_json_code.php" file. You only need to make sure they have the SAME NAME.

Hope that helps,

Vq.

Comment: Really thanks for your old but valid answer. I didn't see any of that in docs!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're misusing JSONP in your server script.

When you receive a request with a callback parameter, you should render the following:

```
callbackName({ "myName": "myValue"});
```

Where `callbackName` is the value of the callback parameter.

Comment: The jQuery spec allows for "callback=?" when using jQuery.getJSON. This wraps the response in a callback function.

Comment: @jerome: Yes, but your server-side script must support it.  JSONP is not magic.

Comment: thanks for your insight on this. If you have a moment, see the links below for my test case. I don't have enough information yet to know why the cross domain request is not allowing me to use the data.

http://www.thespacebetweenthewords.org/json_test/test_jsonp_request.html
Request is made to another domain. "invalid label" console error in Firebug, and unable to use the data.

http://www.globaloperative.info/json_test/test_json_request.html
Request is made to the same domain. Data is retrieved and evaluated correctly.

Comment: You need server-side code to emit the function call.  JSONP does not magically retrieve data from a different domain; it needs a compatible server-side script to emit a function call based on the `callback` parameter. See [here](http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/jsonp-quickly/).