# Parse Nested JSON With JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm new to JSON and really struggling with this. I've read countless other posts and web pages but can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using PHP to output JSON (from data from the database) with this code:

```
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "x0": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Rob",
        "online": "1",
        "gender": "m",
        "age": "29",
        "height": "5'8''",
        "build": "Average",
        "ethnicity": "White",
        "description": "Art geek person",
        "looking_for": "Anything",
        "image": "4fs5d43f5s4d3f544sdf.jpg",
        "last_active": "29-06-11-1810",
        "town": "Manchester",
        "country": "UK",
        "distance": 0.050973560712308
    },
    "x1": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Dave",
        "online": "1",
        "gender": "m",
        "age": "29",
        "height": "5'8''",
        "build": "Average",
        "ethnicity": "White",
        "description": "Art geek person",
        "looking_for": "Anything",
        "image": "4fs5d43f5s4d3f544sdf.jpg",
        "last_active": "29-06-11-1810",
        "town": "Manchester",
        "country": "UK",
        "distance": 0.050973560712308
    }
}
```

I think the problem I'm having is that the JSON is nested(might be wrong there)?.

This is the JQuery:

```
function fetchProfiles() {
    var url='http://url.com/here';
    var i = 0;
    var handle = 'x'.i;

    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        $.each(json.results,function(i,profile){
           $("#profiles").append('<p><img src="'+profile.handle.image+'" widt="48" height="48" />'+profile.handle.name+'</p>');
           i++;
        });
    });
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Does your JSON look exactly like this? I'd expect an array… And does it really have a root key called "results"?

Comment: The top level of a JSON file can be an object or an array.

Comment: Yes that's the JSON output from PHP. Good point about .results - copy and paste error there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think that the problem is that you call $.each on json.results (if the json is exactly what you showed us).

you sholud do:

```
    $.each(json,function(i,profile){
       $("#profiles").append('<p><img src="'+profile.image+'" widt="48" height="48" />'+profile.name+'</p>');
    });
```

look at the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ENcVd/1/ (it alerst the image property of you json object)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the example works perfectly. I think my problem might be with the URL I'm pulling the JSON from. It displays in the browser, but using the jsfiddle code it just alerts undefined?

Comment: Also in Firebug console the GET url is red, but has a 200 OK server response?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the server you are making the request to is not on the same domain of the page making the request. Is it so?
In any case, if you have a complete fiddle, i'll try to help!

Comment: Ah yes that's right, I'm building an app in PhoneGap (js script running locally) that is getting the url from another server. Can this not be done? Thanks again.

Comment: I think you must use $.ajax() and set crossDomain option to true. Look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, I needed to use JSONP and the jsoncallback. The second answer from this thread helped me out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822609/invalid-label-firebug-error-with-jquery-getjson