# Jquery ajax: Invalid label

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

My code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://tinysong.com/b/Beethoven?format=json&key=<my key..>',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Firebug says "invalid label". But when i visit the url in my browser, i see:

```
{"Url":"http:\/\/tinysong.com\/7Wm7","SongID":8815585,"SongName":"Moonlight Sonata","ArtistID":1833,"ArtistName":"Beethoven","AlbumID":258724,"AlbumName":"Beethoven: Piano Sonatas"}
```

Looks like a corret json-string to me. Am i missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Could you share more of the surrounding code? Perhaps there is something the matter there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's JSON.  You're asking for a JSONp string in the dataType, which would require your output to be wrapped in a function.

Comment: Ok, well since its on another domain i suppose its need to be jsonp?

Comment: Yes, which means the other domain has to support building the JSONp.

Comment: Ok, but when i specify json as the format, this is what i get. Is there any other way to solve this from my side, or do they have to supply me with a jsonp-object instead?

Comment: Either they have to supply you with a JSONp object, or you have to create a bridge on the same server as your primary.  The server then gets the JSON, and simply wraps it in a JSONp function.  This requires some level of access to executable server code, whether it be PHP, JSP, C# or whatever else you might be using.  It is pretty drop-dead simple in PHP:  `<?php echo $_REQUEST['jsoncallback'].'('.file_get_contents('http://server/data.json').')'; ?>`  This is simplistic, I like to use serial #s and other goo for this sort of thing, but this is illustrative.

Comment: Thanks John, guess ill have to do it on the serverside

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$.getJSON('http://tinysong.com/b/Beethoven?format=json&key=<my key..>&callback=?', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822609/invalid-label-firebug-error-with-jquery-getjson). Hovewer, if you are performing request from the same domain, you dont have to use jsonp, so you could replace `dataType: 'jsonp',` with `dataType: 'json',`