# getting songs from tinysong

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, grooveshark

I wan't to get a list of songs via the tinysong API which grabs it from [Grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com/) I'm doing it via `$.ajax` and so far i got this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://tinysong.com/s/Beethoven?format=json&key='+key,
    type : 'get',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    succes : function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $('.content').append(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.warn('ERROR');
        console.warn(error);
    }
});
```

Where `key` it's the API key they assigned me. I'm getting the following error :

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://tinysong.com/s/Beethoven?format=json&key=HERE_IS_MY_KEY&callback=jQuery172021696692402474582_1344209008518&_=1344209008523".

However if I go to that url I do get the results printed out like so:

> [{"Url":"http://tinysong.com/Aoxo","SongID":25802452,"SongName":"Symphony No. 7 in A major, Op. 92: Allegretto","ArtistID":1833,"ArtistName":"Beethoven","AlbumID":4497124,"AlbumName":"Beethoven: 9 Symphonien, Ouvert\u00fcren (1 of 6), Berstein, Leonard"},{"Url":"http://tinysong.com/jh4X","SongID":2909282,"SongName":"Piano Concerto No. 5 in E flat major op. 73 'Emperor'","ArtistID":1833,"ArtistName":"Beethoven","AlbumID":268605,"AlbumName":"The Best Of Beethoven"},{"Url":"http://tinysong.com/JhLy","SongID":31825464,"SongName":"Beethoven: Piano Sonata #23 In F Minor, Op. 57, \"Appassionata\"","ArtistID":1833,"ArtistName":"Beethoven","AlbumID":4913792,"AlbumName":"Beethoven's Greatest Hits"},{"Url":"http://tinysong.com/6Jk1","SongID":4925300,"SongName":"Beethoven #4: Adagio","ArtistID":1833,"ArtistName":"Beethoven","AlbumID":842118,"AlbumName":"Beethoven: Symphonies Nos. 7 & 4"},{"Url":"http://tinysong.com/gGW0","SongID":11896153,"SongName":"F\u00fcr Elise","ArtistID":1833,"ArtistName":"Beethoven","AlbumID":2087629,"AlbumName":"Beethoven and the Sea"}]

How can i get this information passed to my javascript ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "error" you are getting is only a warning. Tinysong transfers the JSON response with a wrong content type ("text/html"). You can verify this with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se), e.g.:

```
curl --head http://tinysong.com/s/Beethoven\?format\=json\&key\=<your key>
```

The explanation why your script is not working and a solution for your problem can found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7009439/1351202) (please read also the comments).

Maybe you should contact Tinysong, report the bug regarding the content type and ask for JSONP support.