# Jsonp /Ajax returns - Syntax Error : invalid label

Tags: jquery, jsonp

My code looks like below.. not sure what is the problem..

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.getJSON("http://dev9.edisbest.com/json.php?symbol=IBM&callback=?", 
function(data) {
    alert("Symbol: " + data.symbol + ", Price: " + data.price);
});
</script>
```

My JSON.PHP page code is below

```
<?
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print json_encode(array("symbol" => "IBM", "price" => 91.42));
?>
```

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822609/invalid-label-firebug-error-with-jquery-getjson) hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the JSON string returned from `dev9.edisbest.com` server is invalid.

Now returned:

```
{symbol: 'IBM', price: 91.42}
```

which is invalid. Consider having the following lines in your PHP back end:

```
<?php
$json = json_encode(array(
    "symbol" => "IBM",
    "price" => 91.42
));

header("Content-Type: application/json");
print $_GET['callback'] . "(" . $json . ")";
?>
```

Comment: @user580950 What if you send `application/json` header before output?

Comment: application/json in my PHP page ?

Comment: @user580950 Sure. You need to do the following: `<?php header("Content-Type: application/json"); print json_encode(array("symbol" => "IBM", "price" => 91.42)); ?>`.

Comment: i changed the PHP code still no alert yet, it throws Syntax Error : invalid label in Firefox

Comment: @user580950 Yes, I forgot that you work with JSONP. Check my answer update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    alert("Symbol: " + data['symbol'] + ", Price: " + data['price']);