# Struggling with a small json and php to get IP

Tags: php, jquery, json

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$return['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
$results[] = array(
      'ip' => $return['ip']
   );
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.com/json/",
        function(data){
            console.log(data.ip);
        });
    });
```

But when I run the jQuery I've checked Fire bug and it says the following

> GET http://domain.com/json/ 200 OK 81ms

And doesn't respond with the IP that I requested for. Have I missed something?

**UPDATED CODE**

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$return['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
$results = array(
      'ip' => $return['ip']
   );
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.com/json/", function(data){
            console.log(data.ip);
        });
```

**Firebug Error**

> SyntaxError: invalid label {"ip":"XXX.XXX.XXX.X"}

An arrow points at the first quotation mark just before the word ip.

Comment: If you're accessing JSON on a different domain, [you probably need to use JSON-P instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2681466/901048). AJAX requests can normally only go to the same domain as the page making the request.

Comment: isn't the field called 'id'?

Comment: Look at the [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822609/invalid-label-firebug-error-with-jquery-getjson).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning:

```
[{'ip': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'}]
```

But you are treating it as if you are returning:

```
{'ip': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'}
```

You either need to change your JavaScript to `console.log(data[0].ip)` or change your PHP to: `$results = array( ... );` rather than `$results[] = array( ... );`

Either will fix your problem. :)

Comment: im getting SyntaxError: invalid label pointing to the "ip" of the return

Comment: Please can you update your question with the code you're now using, and the *exact* error message it is giving you in response?